# JavaFX Canvas: Drawing dashed lines

Tags: javafx-2

I'm using JavaFX [GraphicsContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html) for immediate mode drawing on a [Canvas](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/canvas/Canvas.html).

Is it possible to draw dashed lines?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There is a method [setLineDashes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html#setLineDashes-double...-) for dashed line and everything is as before:

```
...
gc.setStroke(Color.RED);
gc.setLineWidth(1);
gc.setLineDashes(2);
gc.strokeLine(x1, y1, x1, y1);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
GC.setLineWidth(2);
GC.setStroke(LASSO_COLOR);
GC.beginPath();
hdashed(x0, x1, y0);
hdashed(x0, x1, y1);
vdashed(x0, y0, y1);
vdashed(x1, y0, y1);
GC.closePath();
GC.stroke();

private void hdashed(double x0, double x1, double yy)
{
    boolean on = true;
    GC.moveTo(x0, yy);
    for (double xx=x0; xx<=x1; xx+=DASH_LENGTH) {
        if (on) GC.lineTo(xx, yy);
        else GC.moveTo(xx, yy);
        on = !on;
    }
}

private void vdashed(double xx, double y0, double y1)
{
    boolean on = true;
    GC.moveTo(xx, y0);
    for (double yy=y0; yy<=y1; yy+=DASH_LENGTH) {
        if (on) GC.lineTo(xx, yy);
        else GC.moveTo(xx, yy);
        on = !on;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This feature has been added in JFX 8u40. See [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html#setLineDashes-double...-) for details.