# JavaFx 2.x : How to draw a dashed line effect on a path

Tags: java, javafx

I am using a path to be able to draw a series of bezier curves.

However, I need to make the fill a dashed effect as opposed to a solid fill.

I have seen this article : [JavaFx 2.x : How to draw dashed or dotted lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786363/javafx-2-x-how-to-draw-dashed-or-dotted-lines), but it deals with putting shape objects onto the stage, whereas I am drawing directly to the GraphicsContext for creating a jpg image.

Is it possible to do this ?

---

EDIT:
This is how I am drawing the line at present :

```
// cv is a Canvas object, previously created and initialised earlier
cv.beginPath();
cv.moveTo(x, y);
cv.cubicTo(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);

// Either finish with this
cv.closePath();
cv.fill();

// or this
cv.setLineWidth(0.5);
cv.stroke();
```

Comment: Show your current code where you add a solid filled path.

Comment: @UlukBiy - just added the code as requested.

Answer (score 1):

According to [RT-37999](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-37999), it is implemented (fixed) in Java 8u40, which is downloadable for early access. It is expected GA release date is March 2015.

Until that time imo you need to implement workarounds yourself like [JavaFX Canvas: Drawing dashed lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797325/javafx-canvas-drawing-dashed-lines).

Alternatively, read the implementation code of RT-37999, and if it is not too complex, integrate it to your project by extending related api classes.

Comment: I looked at the article you mentioned, but it implements dashes on straight lines only.  This will not work on curved, bezier, paths. I'll have to create an account to see the implementation you noted here and see if it is a feasible option.

Comment: I looked at the new dashed stroke code and have seen that it not only adds new java classes, but also has a new C code module which does the actual dashing.  This means, at least for myself, that it is an unfeasible option for trying to implement it beforehand.  Is there any other, java base, solution I could go with ?