# Dashes bleed through solid line in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

In a JavaFX program I draw a black, one-pixel dashed line. When I draw a black, one-pixel
solid line on top of it I can still see the dashes bleeding through the solid line.
This happens whether I stroke the lines on a Canvas, or use Line nodes with *smooth* set
to true.

Why is that? Is there a way to stop it?

Sample program and image attached.

[image]

```
package sandbox2;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        launch( args );
    }

    @Override
    public void start( Stage primaryStage ) throws Exception
    {
        primaryStage.setTitle( "Fx Playground" );

        Group   root    = new Group();
        Scene   scene   = new Scene( root, 350, 100 );
        primaryStage.setScene( scene );

        Line    line1  = new Line( 50, 50, 300, 50 );
        line1.setStroke( Color.BLACK );
        line1.getStrokeDashArray().addAll( 5. );
        line1.setSmooth( true );

        Line    line2  = new Line( 50, 50, 300, 50 );
        line2.setStroke( Color.BLACK );
        line2.setSmooth( true );

        ObservableList<Node>    nodes   = root.getChildren();
        nodes.add( line1 );
        nodes.add( line2 );

        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: is this helpful?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797325/javafx-canvas-drawing-dashed-lines

Comment: It seems like the solid line does not have full opacity, have you checked `line2's` opacity via `line2.getOpacity()`?

Comment: Are you doing this for the sake of doing it? Why not just use one line and switch between making it solid or dashed?

Comment: 21797325, and several other similar questions don't address stroking one line over another

Comment: I set the opacity to 100% and it changed nothing

Comment: Why am I doing it - the solid line is animated over the dashed line, so that the dashed line gradually disappears.

Comment: Can you move the starting and/or end points to get the same effect?

Comment: On which platform do you see this behaviour? I just see a solid line as expected on my Mac (Retina)

Answer (score 2):

You should change the line constructors to `new Line( 50.5, 50.5, 300, 50 )` I assume that will solve the problem. For an explanation see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html

Comment: Great lead pointing me back to Shape.html; but using the revised constructor arguments gets me something different, but still not what I expect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could increase the top `Line`'s stroke width by 1 more than the bottom `Line`.

> Add this code:

```
line2.setStrokeWidth(2);
```

Comment: Setting the strokeWidth to 2 causes the dashed line to be totally obscured; but I'm still curious why a 1-pixel line won't do the same thing.

Comment: I am not sure either.